# ¿Cómo agregar más opciones en Datatables?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Si por ejemplo quiero añadir a Datatables la opción de mostrar los elementos de la tabla según por fecha, un ejemplo así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
      "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
   } );
 } );
```

Pero además quiero agregar la opción de cambiar el idioma de los elementos

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
        "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
        "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "No records available",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
    }
} );
} );
```

Y además poner otra opción que involucre agrupar los elementos por categoría, por así decirlo.

```
// Order by the grouping
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
    var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
    if ( currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
        table.order( [ groupColumn, 'desc' ] ).draw();
    }
    else {
        table.order( [ groupColumn, 'asc' ] ).draw();
    }
} );
} );
```

¿Cómo podría añadir estos elementos de manera que todos funcionen al 100? Ya que al intentar añadirlos en un solo código `<script>` me sale error y no llegan a activarse.

De antemano, gracias por su amable ayuda. Buen día.

Answer (score 0):

¿Donde te sale error? En consola o en HTML5?
Cada fragmento de código funciona independientemente? Entonces todo lo que sea debe ir dentro de:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ...
});
```

Dentro de éste no debe ir otra `.ready(function())`,

sino: `$("#example tbody").on("click", "tr.group", function() { ... })`, `$('#example').DataTable({ ... })`.